# Winforms C# pass variable between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do i pass `name` value from Form1 to Form2?

> Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string name = "xxx";
}
```

> Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblname.Text = name;
    }
}
```

---

## Solution:

> Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = "xxx";
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(name);
        frm2.Show();
    }
}
```

> Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string name)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Asked thousand times, google your title which you should have done before you've asked this.

Comment: Should i have mentioned i searched 100 times?

Comment: Then you need to work on your googling skills.  I feel like I see this question asked (and closed as a dupe) every other day.

Comment: @roryap Did u ever asked yourself why?

Comment: @Cris -- yes, and the answer is there are too many people who don't know how to research.  Once a question as simple to find as this has been asked once, it should not be asked again.

Comment: @Cris https://www.google.com/search?q=Winforms+C%23+pass+variable+between+forms

Comment: Look, I selected your question title, right-clicked on it, choose "google..." and here's what it came up with.  Thousands...  https://www.google.com/search?q=Winforms+C%23+pass+variable+between+forms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Cris Then you should start from the basics again. Because that's basics.

Comment: Frustating is to see people who don't care to invest a minimum effort on research

Comment: Since Matias solution is not recommended, i turned out doing more research and found an easy to understand solution here: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/passvalues.html .  I find both links posted as the solution as hard to understand for my current C# level.

Answer (score 0):

One easy but not recommended solution would be to make the field static:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string name = "xxx";
}
```

Then you can simply read it from the other form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    lblName.Text = Form1.name;
}
```

Comment: Using static variables is a recipe for disaster.  I've worked on forms apps written this way, and, unless you want to spend your career chasing down impossible-to-find bugs, static variables should be reserved for global, mostly-immutable data.

Comment: @DVK I totally agree with you. In fact, I did clarify that this is not recommended at all.